# Request parameters from FullCalendar not received in Route

Tags: laravel, http, request, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Calendar and events work flawlessly except the request parameters `start` and `end` from fullcalendar are not received by the route. `$request` is completely empty.

My calendar:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var FEED_URL = "{{url('/')}}" + "/event-feed";
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ],
            events: {
                url: FEED_URL
            }
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
</script>
```

My route:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/event-feed', function (Request $request) {
    $eventOutput = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'resourceId' => 'a',
            'title' => 'Test',
            'start' => '2020-06-11T00:00:00.000000Z',
            'end' => '2020-06-11T02:00:00.000000Z',
            'left' => $request->input('start'), //null
            'right' => $request->input('end'), //null
            'uri' => $request->path()
        ]
     ];
    return json_encode($eventOutput);
});
```

The resulting feed is:

```
[{"id":1,"resourceId":"a","title":"Test","start":"2020-06-11T00:00:00.000000Z","end":"2020-06-11T02:00:00.000000Z","left":null,"right":null,"uri":"event-feed"}]
```

I also tried `php artisan serve` to see if its my Wamp server but the problem is the same. I also set up a vanilla Laravel 7 install and the problem is the same. Anyone has an idea where to look?

Comment: any error in console? I pasted your code in my test with fullcalendar and it works fine...

Comment: no error on console but i have just seen in firefox/devtools/networkanalysis that the get request is `http://localhost/vanilli/public/event-feed?start=2020-05-31T00:00:00+02:00&end=2020-07-12T00:00:00+02:00` but it does not seem to reach the route.

Comment: Is request status code: 200 OK ?

Comment: yes, it's 200 OK. what could cut out the parameters?

Comment: Then I really do not have a clue since your code is working without any problem for me... In my response: `left:2020-05-31T00:00:00+02:00` and `right:2020-07-12T00:00:00+02:00`, so it is not null at all.

Answer (score -1):

I never use FullCalendar but I notice that on the Doc that parameters pass by GET method.

I dont know if you add on your routes.php file the

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

because you use `Request $request` on the same `web.php` file so if you add the `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` you can get all data I tested on Laravel 7 and work

[image]

[image]

I hope this help you!

Comment: Thanks but I am already using `Illuminate\Http\Request;` in my web.php, that's not it I guess. 

`use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;`